# Different scale in bar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am creating a bar plot for a situation, however the scale of each bar is different and should be represented in the scale of 10. My code is:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{gray}{ % define a new cycle list
     {fill=black!20},
     {fill=black!40},
     {fill=black!60}
    }


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      ymin = 0, ymax = 25,
      ybar,
      bar width=17, % added
      enlarge x limits=0.3,
      legend  style={at={(0.7 ,1)},
      anchor=north,legend  columns =-1},
      ylabel ={Gas Cost and Price in ETH},
      xlabel ={Sources Quantity},
      symbolic x coords ={7,14,21},
      xtick=data,
      nodes  near  coords ,
      nodes  near  coords  align ={vertical},
      nodes near coords style={font=\tiny}, % reduce font size of nodes near coords
      cycle list name=gray, % use the new cycle list
    ]

    \addplot  coordinates  {(7,11) (14,15) (21,19)};
    \addplot  coordinates  {(7,5) (14,7) (21,9)};

     \addlegendentry{Gas}
     \addlegendentry{ETH}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My values are:

```
%7:   0.11449906 ETH - 5 724 953 Gas
%14: 0.153421 ETH     - 7 671 050 Gas
%21: 0.1962195 ETH -  9 810 975 Gas
```

- How could I represent the value shown above the bars on a scale of ten (i.e., 5.75 * 10⁶)

Comment: Not quite, you also need `ylabel ={Gas Cost \& Price in ETH},`, i.e. a `\&` instead of `&`. Note that your MWE produces an interesting effect. When one fixes the `&` the code runs through but it no longer does so once one adds `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`.

Comment: Changed it for "and"

Comment: You also need something like `bar width=17pt` if you use a more recent version. That is, you need to add units to the bar width.

Comment: With my edit the MVE is complete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93838/discussion-between-mutante-and-marmot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to read the values into a table, and do some scaling here and there with `visualization depends on` and `y expr`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

    \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{gray}{ % define a new cycle list
     {fill=black!20},
     {fill=black!40},
     {fill=black!60}
    }


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{
       p  ETH  gas
       7  0.11449906 5724953
      14 0.153421   7671050
      21 0.1962195  9810975
     }\DataTable
    \begin{axis}[
      ymin = 0, ymax = 25,
      ybar,
      bar width=17pt, % added
      enlarge x limits=0.3,
      legend  style={at={(0.7 ,1)},
      anchor=north,legend  columns =-1},
      ylabel ={Gas Cost and Price in ETH},
      xlabel ={Sources Quantity},
      xtick=data,
      xticklabels from table={\DataTable}{p}, % instead of symbolic coords
      nodes  near  coords  align ={vertical},
      nodes near coords style={font=\tiny}, % reduce font size of nodes near coords
      cycle list name=gray, % use the new cycle list
    ]

     \addplot  +[
       visualization depends on=y*1e-2\as\RawY,
       nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\RawY}}
       ]  
           table[x expr=\coordindex, y expr=\thisrow{ETH}*1e2] {\DataTable};
     \addplot  +[
       visualization depends on=y*1e6\as\RawY,
       nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\RawY}},
       node near coords style={anchor=south west,rotate=45}]
            table[x expr=\coordindex, y expr=\thisrow{gas}*1e-6] {\DataTable};

     \addlegendentry{ETH}
     \addlegendentry{Gas}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal. Note that I had to add dimensions to the bar width in order to be able to compile it with the most recent version of pgfplots.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\begin{document}

    \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{gray}{ % define a new cycle list
     {fill=black!20},
     {fill=black!40},
     {fill=black!60}
    }


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      ymin = 0, ymax = 25,
      ybar,
      bar width=17pt, % added
      enlarge x limits=0.3,
      legend  style={at={(0.7 ,1)},
      anchor=north,legend  columns =-1},
      ylabel ={Gas Cost and Price in ETH},
      xlabel ={Sources Quantity},
      symbolic x coords ={7,14,21},
      xtick=data,
      nodes  near  coords  align ={vertical},
      nodes near coords style={font=\tiny}, % reduce font size of nodes near coords
      cycle list name=gray, % use the new cycle list
    ]
    %7:   0.11449906 ETH - 5 724 953 Gas
    %14: 0.153421 ETH     - 7 671 050 Gas
    %21: 0.1962195 ETH -  9 810 975 Gas
    \edef\myLstA{0.11449906,0.153421,0.1962195}
    \addplot+[nodes  near  coords=\pgfmathparse{{\myLstA}[\coordindex]}%
      \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}]  coordinates  {(7,11) (14,15) (21,19)};
    \edef\myLstB{5724953,7671050,9810975}
    \addplot+[nodes  near  coords=\pgfmathparse{{\myLstB}[\coordindex]}%
      \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult},
      nodes near coords style={xshift=1.5ex,yshift=3.5ex,rotate=70}]  coordinates  {(7,5) (14,7) (21,9)};

     \addlegendentry{Gas}
     \addlegendentry{ETH}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]